# RoboSpice: How to fire the RequestListener.onRequestFailure method in a SpiceRequest

Tags: java, android, request, listener, robospice

I have a class which extends `SpiceRequest`, but I need to call the `onRequestFailure(SpiceException)` method when a failure has occured in the `loadDataFromNetwork()` method. I tried to throw an exception inside that method but that doesn't fire the `onRequestFailure(SpiceException)` method.

How could I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sure something is wrong in your code, if you really throw an exception, it will be wrapped inside a SpiceException. Invoke spiceException.getCause() to get your original exception.

Check the logs, you should see that exception being processed inside RoboSpice. Maybe something wrong happens before with the cache, but normally the exception will be passed to the listener.

Comment: There was indeed something wrong with my code. It works now, thanks!

Comment: Offtopic comment: I saw that you have contributed to the robospice project, but is there a way to persist ArrayList without a wrapper class?

Comment: No, RS needs a strong class as it uses it as a key (indeed class is part of a compound key, with requestCacheKey also). So RS really needs a distinguishable class. But you can add one in one line : public static class Foo.List extends ArrayList<Foo> {}